# Typescript — make sure object prop key is same as prop value

Tags: typescript

I need to type the following object structure:

```
const entities = {
  abc: {
    id: 'abc'
  },
  def: {
    id: 'def'
  }
}
```

Each object prop key needs to match its corresponding `id`.

---

I tried doing this:

```
interface EntitiesMap<E extends Entity> {
  [K in E['id']]: E;
}

interface Entity {
  id: string;
}
```

But this does not ensure that the prop key and `id` value match. For example:

```
const entities = {
  ghi: {
    id: 'aaaaa' // should throw an error as ghi doesn't match aaaaa
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I could make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The way I know is to define a type. But you need always to care about keys.

```js
type Entity<T extends keyof any> = {
  [K in T]: {
    id: K;
  };
};

const entities: Entity<'abc' | 'def' | 'def2' | 'def3'> = {
  abc: {
    id: 'abc'
  },
  def: {
    id: 'def'
  },
  def2: {
    id: 'abc' // <- fails
  },
  def3: {
    id: 'def4' // <- fails
  },
}
```

For keys you can have a helper function, not sure if it's acceptable

```js
const validateEntities = <K extends keyof any>(value: Entity<K>): Entity<K> => {
  return value;
};

const entities = validateEntities({
  abc: {
    id: 'abc'
  },
  def: {
    id: 'def'
  },
  def2: {
    id: 'abc' // <- fails
  },
  def3: {
    id: 'def4' // <- fails
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you defined `id` as `string` and `'aaaaa'` is a string. you can use something like this for `id` which is one step more specific than `string`:

```
type IdType = keyof typeof entities // "abc" | "def"

// and use it as id type

interface Entity {
  id: IdType
}
```

It's maybe not the exact answer you're looking for , but it's a good start. hope it would be helpfull

Comment: Thanks, I've tried something similar too but got stuck. Thanks for the suggestion nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK to use identity function to create the entities, you can use generics to infer the root keys and mapped type to verify the values of the inner objects:

```
const createEntities = <TKeys extends string>(entities: { [K in TKeys]: { id: K } }) => entities;

// OK
const entities = createEntities({
  abc: {
    id: 'abc'
  },
  def: {
    id: 'def'
  }
})

// Error: type '"aaaaa"' is not assignable to type '"ghi"'
createEntities({
  ghi: {
    id: 'aaaaa'
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBRMUCWPERgF4YAeAFQGlEBPAxADzTABMDp5swBzAPgApEWXNnwAuGAG8YAbQoxOMSjQgBdcVOzNxcgL4wdASiI8YgnHggBuAFDWA9HZgB5CtdCRYZ4fiJwkqDCELPglrGBhkACNgdTDw%20S0YAHIo4CS4nQAaOOZEADNY%20ITxJNy89PCda0NbBxh0eHgQeHEoagAHRGSAImQ%20vu6k%20QIwEFhkCAhsLjAogBsuqBAYNs6ergALbEG3fzRMcxEIELjN7EL4zRL%20vor9aoMgA)

Comment: That's a great idea — I'll consider it. Do you know if it would it be possible without the create function?

Comment: If you know the keys upfront - yes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with a simple type signature, but if you declare `entities` with `as const`, it is possible to do this entirely at the type level, without any JavaScript functions:

```
type ValidEntities<E> = {[K in keyof E]: {id: K}}
type IsValid<E extends ValidEntities<E>> = true // Can be any type

// OK
const entities = {
  abc: {
    fine: 3,
    id: 'abc'
  },
  def: {
    id: 'def'
  }
} as const

type Validate = IsValid<typeof entities>
```

If `entities` is invalid, you will get a type error at `IsValid<typeof entities>`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)